# getting a string instead of html returned from function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, gatsby

At the top of my gatsby blog (a react component) I have a function that gets a url's extension, and based on whether it's an image or a video it returns a line of html like so:

```
  const printPicOrVid = function(myUrl) {
    let fileExt =
      myUrl.substring(myUrl.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, myUrl.length) || myUrl
    if (fileExt === "jpg" || fileExt === "png" || fileExt === "gif") {
      return '<img src="https:' + myUrl + '" />'
    } else if (fileExt === "mp4") {
      return '<video src="https:' + myUrl + '"></video>'
    }
  }
```

which successfully returns a string of something like `<img src="https://contentful.com/whatever/image.jpg" />`

in my **return** part of the react page I have:

```
{edge.node.heroImage && printPicOrVid(edge.node.heroImage.file.url)}
```

which is saying: if the heroImage from contentful exists, then return the jpg or mp4 html. The problem is, I just get a string of the HTML printed to the page, not the html rendering an actual image or video like intended.

have a feeling the answer here is dangerously set inner HTML, but not sure how to implement. Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Actually yeah, Ismael's is a better idea. Just return the JSX img or video element, and make the `src` the dynamic string, rather than the whole element a string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When returning JSX in a function, you should just plainly return the JSX element you want. So you'd write `return <div/>` instead of `return '<div/>'`. So:

```
return '<img src="https:' + myUrl + '" />'
```

Should be

```
return <img src={"https:" + myUrl} />
```

Otherwise you'd return a string instead of JSX. Same in the other return statement, which should be:

```
return <video src={"https:" + myUrl}></video>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to return a `<div />` with attribute `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` set to `{{ __html: printPicOrVid(edge.node.heroImage.file.url) }}`.

Full code:

```
{edge.node.heroImage && <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: printPicOrVid(edge.node.heroImage.file.url) }} />}
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured I should avoid dangerouslySetInnerHTML if possible though so I went with Ismael's solution, appreciate the answer though.